# How to generate samples of Gaussian scale mixture?

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution

If I want to generate multivariate Gaussian scale mixture samples with given location and covariance (characteristic matrix) of sample how will I generate that with any mixture distribution?

For example if I want to generate samples of Gaussian scale mixture with mean 0 and Covariance R let the mixture distribution be exponential or Laplace. How to generate that?

Comment: You'd also need to specify the mixing distribution on the scale parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your question, carefully defining what you mean by each of the terms you are using. If this is for some class, add the `self-study` tag and modify your question to follow the guidelines there.

Comment: I hope now I am clear with question. It is not for some class or book. I need to do some simulations for that I need to include Gaussian scale samples as my noise. For that I want to generate the samples.

Comment: How does this problem arise?

Comment: Yes so for adding noise which is (Gaussian Scale mixture) in my case I need a samples with some variance.

Comment: If you only needed to "add noise" you could accomplish that simply by increasing the variance. Note that a scale mixture\* implies a particular kind of multivariate structure in your data.    $\quad$ \*(assuming I understand, but given your followup questions to my earlier answer I really think I don't, which is why I deleted it -- hopefully temporarily - until it's clear what you're really doing here. I have asked for you to define what you mean when you say scale mixture of Gaussians, but you haven't done so in a way that is clear. Do you have a reference?)

Comment: Yes thats was only my question was as u said I can accomplish by simply increasing variance. How to do that I wanted to ask now let us suppose I want to add  noise such having Gaussian scale mixture as distribution let SNR ie signal to noise power as 10dB assuming signal power is 1 my variance of noise will be (1/10). Now how to generate gaussian scale sample with variance (1/10). This is exaclty I wanted to ask. I dont have any reference I have just read https://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring06/sta376/Support/RegressionETC/west.biometrika.1987.pdf this paper for scale mixture for Gaussian.

Comment: I find much of your previous comment unintelligible.

Comment: Sorry for that actually I think I am not able to ask question properly. May I ask what is not clear in my question so that I can reframe properly again.